# Is there a way to inflate the pop up menu above the button?

Tags: java, android, menu

Here is my problem . Upon click of the button , the menu pops up below the button . But I would prefer ,if it  can pop up above the button . Is there any way to do this ?
Thank you for you time.

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(CalEntry.this, view);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(CalEntry.this);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.log);
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Code? What class are you using for your "pop up"?

Comment: You could use a simple dialog instead of a popupmenu, tell me if you want more details about this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way using `PopupMenu`. However, using `PopupWindow` gives you more flexibility over exactly where it is placed.

It has the method `showAtLocation()` which allows you to set the anchor view and gravity, as well as, the x and y offset.

It has other methods that allow you to configure where it shows but I use `showAtLocation()` to center it directly over the button pressed. You can move it above the anchor `View` by adjusting the y offset. You will just need to play with that value to get it where you want.

You could then use your items in the `menu` as a `ListView` for your `contentView` in your constructor.

[PopupWindow docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)